How to fix the ImportError: cannot import name 'formatargspec' from 'inspect' (/usr/lib/python3.12/inspect.py). Did you mean: 'formatargvalues'?
I'm trying to run django app usind docker .. it gives me this error when i try to docker-compose up --build :
water_maps  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
water_maps  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
water_maps  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
water_maps  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
water_maps  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
water_maps  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
water_maps  |   File "/var/www/html/demo_app/water_maps/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
water_maps  |     from celery import Celery
water_maps  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
water_maps  |     from . import local  # noqa
water_maps  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
water_maps  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/celery/local.py", line 17, in <module>
water_maps  |     from .five import PY3, bytes_if_py2, items, string, string_t
water_maps  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/celery/five.py", line 7, in <module>
water_maps  |     import vine.five
water_maps  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/vine/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
water_maps  |     from .abstract import Thenable
water_maps  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/vine/abstract.py", line 6, in <module>
water_maps  |     from .five import with_metaclass, Callable
water_maps  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/vine/five.py", line 364, in <module>
water_maps  |     from inspect import formatargspec, getargspec as _getargspec  # noqa
water_maps  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
water_maps  | ImportError: cannot import name 'formatargspec' from 'inspect' (/usr/lib/python3.12/inspect.py). Did you mean: 'formatargvalues'?


here is how my Dockerfile looks like :
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

# Avoid tzdata infinite waiting bug
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Africa/Cairo

RUN apt clean
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils vim curl apache2 apache2-utils git
RUN apt-get -y install python3 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
RUN apt -y install certbot python3-certbot-apache
RUN ln /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN apt -y install software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN apt update
#Add sf to avoid ln: failed to create hard link '/usr/bin/pip': File exists
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip --break-system-packages
RUN pip install django ptvsd --break-system-packages
RUN pip uninstall web3.py --break-system-packages
RUN pip install git+https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py.git --break-system-packages
RUN apt install wait-for-it
RUN apt-get -y install gettext
RUN apt-get -y install poppler-utils
RUN apt-get -y install redis-server
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN service apache2 restart
COPY www/demo_app/water_maps/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --break-system-packages
ADD ./demo_site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
EXPOSE 80 5432
WORKDIR /var/www/html/demo_app
#CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
#CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate", "--no-input"]

And here is how my docker-compose.yaml file looks like :
version: "2"

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always 
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./www/:/var/www/html
      - ./www/demo_app/kml_files:/var/www/html/demo_app/kml_files
      - ./www/demo_app/temp_kml_file:/var/www/html/demo_app/temp_kml_file
      - ./www/demo_app/upload:/var/www/html/demo_app/upload
      - ./data/log:/var/log/apache2
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=database_innvoentiq
      - POSTGRES_USER=database_user_innvoentiq
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Yahoo000@

  django-apache2:
    build: .
    container_name: water_maps
    restart: always 
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=database_innvoentiq
      - POSTGRES_USER=database_user_innvoentiq
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Yahoo000@
    ports:
      - 6000:80
      - 6001:443
      # - 80:80
      # - 443:443

    volumes:
      - ./www/:/var/www/html
      - ./www/demo_app/kml_files:/var/www/html/demo_app/kml_files
      - ./www/demo_app/temp_kml_file:/var/www/html/demo_app/temp_kml_file
      - ./www/demo_app/upload:/var/www/html/demo_app/upload
      - ./data/log:/var/log/apache2

      # - ./data/config/etc/apache2:/etc/apache2
    # command: sh -c 'python manage.py migrate && python manage.py loaddata the_db.json '
    command: sh -c 'wait-for-it db:5432 -- python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py compilemessages && apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'
    # command: sh -c 'wait-for-it db:5432 -- python manage.py migrate && python manage.py loaddata last.json && apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'

    depends_on:
      - db


Note that I've removed the Django tag from this question, just because you use Django doesn't mean the question is about it. The docker tag should also be removed but I've left it for now, please edit and reduce your question so it doesn't need that entire docker file, etc. and remove the tag.

The function inspect.formatargspec was last available in Python 3.10 as it was marked as deprecation as per its documentation since Python 3.5, and was noted to be removed as per the release notes of Python 3.11.  Also note that in the current versions of vine (since their 5.0.0 release as per changelog) actually no longer make use of that problematic vine.five module noted in the traceback output.
You will need to update the dependencies for that build, or downgrade to Python 3.10 if the functionality of that deployment depends on that specific legacy version of vine.
